# When pasting in a file the output of some other file, the first row is loosing all columns and joining all row into one cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that I created to copy from a file which is filled with formulas, but :

```
Sub Masterfile2023()

Dim MF As Workbook
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Rg As Range
Dim InputRange As Range
Dim C As Range
Dim i As Long

    'full file path to be referenced.
    Set MF = Workbooks.Open("aa")
    'Range to be copied
    Set Rng = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("bb").Range("QK23:SW" & Cells(Rows.Count, 410).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'Dropdown list button
    Set Rg = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("bb").Range("QL19")
    'Filter range
    Set InputRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("backend").Range("O41:O60").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    'iteration on the dropdowlist for copy
    i = 1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each C In InputRange
    Rg = C.Value
    Rng.Copy
    i = i + 1
    Next C
       
    'Opens new location file
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="dd", ReadOnly:=False)
    Workbooks("ff").Worksheets("Output").Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

But on ff the file has already the first line with some names with (header of the columns purpose), but basically in the end of the code first line is concatenated into one cell.

Maybe visual it will better, so the file originally is like this:

[image]

but then in the end looks liked this:

[image]

Could you help me to find this problem in my code?

I tried to iterate between some drop down list on some file, copy everything from a range during this iteration and paste the output from all items of the iteration together in some other file.

Comment: Your loop does not make sense. Why do you copy in each loop `Rng` if you do not change it? What is that loop suppsed to do?

Comment: There is a file with a dropdown list, and each item of this list InputRange produces a different RNG. so basically my loop is copying every different output from the selection of the dropdown list.